# VLOOKUP Equivalent in SQL Within the Same Table

Tags: sql, join, lookup

I am trying to lookup a manager's name from only the Employee_ID, Manager_ID, Employee Name within the same table.

Here is the data I have to work with.

```
SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeName, Employee_Job_Title, Manager_ID, Managers_Position
```

I'd like the results to look like:

| EmployeeID | EmployeeName | Employee_Job_Title | Manager_ID | ManagerName | Managers_Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Jason | Teller | 2345 | Mason | Teller Manager |

I know this can happen based on some type of join on the EmployeeIDs but I'm not sure how to make it happen.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
    e.EmployeeID,
    e.EmployeeName,
    e.Employee_Job_Title,
    e.Manager_ID,
    m.EmployeeName as ManagerName,
    e.Managers_Position
from employee_table e
left join employee_table m on e.Manager_ID = m.Employee_ID
```

Comment: That worked!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: No problem, you're very welcome, have a great day.